# How to change a boolean value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I want when my site first loads for a value to be false but when a button is clicked I want it to update the value to make it true.

What I've tried so far:

For the HTML

```
<button onclick="button1()"></button>
```

For the JavaScript

```
let button1pressed = false;

function button1(){
  button1pressed = true;
}
```

But the problem with this is that afterwards I have an if statement

```
if(button1pressed === true) {
console.log('The value is now true');
}
```

However the message doesn't log to the console.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: and what is the problem with it?

Comment: You should be able to see now that I have updated the post!

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the condition inside of the event function, because the code is later evaluated and at start the value is `false`.

```js
function button1(){
    if (!button1pressed) {
        button1pressed = true;
        console.log('The value is now true');
    }
}

let button1pressed = false;
```

```html
<button onclick="button1()">click</button>
```

An other approach is to use an interval with a check and get the message only once.

```js
function button1(){
    button1pressed = true;
}

let button1pressed = false,
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (button1pressed) {
            console.log('The value is now true');
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<button onclick="button1()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value in the log, try this:

```js
let button1pressed = false;  

function button1(){
button1pressed = true;

    console.log("The value is now: "+ button1pressed);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="button1()">click</button>
```